# play framework migrate to 2.1.1 gives me a headache

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

So I wanted to start working on a play framework project of mine I abandoned 5 months ago, the project was still in version 2.0.4 and seeing 2.1.1 was the latest version I did this tutorial to update the project: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Migration. (except for doing addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.1") instead to match the current version)

But as soon as I try to do play clean I get this error:

```
[error] sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.
[error] Note that conflicts were resolved for some dependencies:
[error]     asm:asm
[error]     asm:asm-tree
[error]     asm:asm-util
[error]     jline:jline
[error]     junit:junit
[error]     com.jcraft:jsch
[error]     commons-logging:commons-logging
[error]     commons-codec:commons-codec
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I can't find much on the topic except for this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/O4SUjFnQPH4/fa19dNNzt9gJ) but I don't really understand what fixed the issue there and apparently the asker neither. I also tried to add all the example dependencies in the migration tutorial but that changed nothing.

Is this solvable or should I just revert back to 2.0.4?

**EDIT 1-5-12'  *Added config files, nothing out of the ordinairy I think***

Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "Workshop0182Host"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
    )

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here      
    )

}
```

plugins.sbt

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"


// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.1")
```

build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.12.2
```

I have tried to do `addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")` but then `play clean` just says addSbtPlugin uses the wrong version. play clean-all ran fine but nothing changed afterwards

**EDIT 1-5-12'  *Added logs***

Here is a link ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bcfM4MJd)) to the error log when I try to run `play clean` or `play run`, I think the problem has something to do with the scala version but I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: Try `play clean-all` and see if that helps.

Comment: If `play clean` fails, just deleted the `target` folder. It has the same effect.

Comment: Do you use any custom sbt plugins?

Comment: @Marius Soutier No i do not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem, it all turns around sbt version and play version. So in `project/build.properties` you must have `sbt.version=0.12.2` and in `project/plugins.sbt` `addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")` then

```
play clean
play ~run
```

Try to create new project from scratch with 2.0.4 version and then migrate it to 2.1.0

In any way, it would be nice to see your config files.

Comment: So even though I am using play version 2.1.1 I have to use 2.1.0 in plugins.sbt?

Comment: Exactly, you need to use sbt-plugin 2.1.0

Comment: Then I get this: This project uses Play 2.1.0!
Update the Play sbt-plugin version to 2.1.1 (usually in project/plugins.sbt)

Comment: I'm sorry, i was thinking about 2.1.0 and have written a folly, if you use play 2.1.1 than sbt-plugin also 2.1.1. I have just now tried and it works fine. Do you tried to create a new project from scratch with your play-2.1.1 and run it, as it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had to change project/plugins.sbt in order to work on a project a pulled from a github repo

```
// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.2")
```

to

```
    // Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
   addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```